# Copying float values into char array

Tags: c, string, strcpy, strcat

I'm writing a TCP socket in C to send location data for a project I'm working on.

So far, everything works, but I'm struggling with this seemingly simply problem. I'm trying to build a JSON String that will be sent over the socket. I have a character array (representative of the String) `json` defined as:

```
char json[1024];
```

With a method prototype:

```
const char* build_json(void);
```

And method body:

```
const char* build_json(void) {
    strcpy(json, "{");
    strcat(json, "\"latitude\":");
    sprintf(json, "%0.5f", latitude);
    strcat(json, "}");
    return json;
}
```

I know that `latitude` is defined correctly and should be a `float` of approximately 5 decimal places.

But when I call `build_json();`, `38.925034}` is the only thing that is returned. Why is this the case? It appears that the call to `sprintf` is overwriting what's already been written in `json`.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`sprintf` will not append to your string; rather, it will overwrite whatever is there. You could do this:

```
sprintf(json + strlen(json), "%0.5f", 213.33f);
```

But, to be honest, this is a much better solution:

```
sprintf(json, "{\"latitude\":%0.5f}", location);
```

And this solution is still better:

```
snprintf(json, sizeof(json), "{\"latitude\":%0.5f}", location);
json[sizeof(json) - 1] = '\0';
```

as long as `json` is an array visible to the function that calls `snprintf`, i.e. allocated in that function on the stack, or globally. If it's a `char*` that you pass to the function, this will fail miserably, so beware.

Comment: But the first solution looks really neat!

Comment: @BarmakShemirani Matter of taste, I guess :P There's no overflow check there, though, so I'd rather use `snprintf` just to make sure.

Comment: Using `snprintf()` is a wise advice here.  When printing with `"%f"`, the resultant string could be hundreds or thousands of bytes long (think `-DBL_MAX`).

Answer (score 1):

You had better to do this only with sprintf to avoid multiple operations.

```
const char* build_json(void) {
    sprintf(json, "{\"latitude\":%0.5f}", latitude);
    return json;
}
```

Moreover if you are writing network code, you had better to allocate your string in your function and not relying on global. Often, network code are done in a multi-thread way.

Answer (score 0):

Quick & dirty fix:

```
char* cptr = json;
...
strcpy(cptr, "{");
cptr += sizeof("{") - 1;

strcat(cptr, "\"latitude\":");
cptr += sizeof("\"latitude\":") - 1;

sprintf(cptr, "%0.5f", latitude);
```

The proper solution would be put the string literals and their sizes in constant variables instead of the above.

```
char* cptr = json;
...
strcpy(cptr, STR_START_BRACE);
cptr += STR_START_BRACE_LEN;

strcat(cptr, STR_LATITUDE);
cptr += STR_LATITUDE_LEN;

sprintf(cptr, "%0.5f", latitude);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may write the whole string at once in buffer:

```
const void build_json(char * json, size_t *len) 
{
    char buff[50];
    sprintf(buff, "{\"latitude\":%0.5f}", latitude);
    *len = strlen(buff);
    strncpy(json, buff, *len);
}
```

Just provide enough space for buffer, you need to allocate your json outside of the func and free it when out of scope

Comment: The `strncpy()` misses to copy the `0`-termination. And why (the intermediate) use of `buf` at all?

Comment: it depends on the usage, we have no clue what is the consumer of the function, From word "json" I assumed it would be net send - then you have length to be able to send and in such case you do not care about zero termination

Comment: No need to call `strlen` after you `sprintf` btw, since `sprintf` returns the number of characters written to the buffer.